# LibGDX. Можно ли в ShapeRenderer получить фигуру с вычитанием пересечения с другой фигурой?

Tags: java, разработка-игр, libgdx, shape

Например, есть круг и квадрат, квадрат проходит одним ребром через центр круга. При вычитании пересечения квадрата и круга из круга остаётся полукруг. Это возможно?

Comment: Используя стенсил, или кастомные шейдеры, или тест глубины

Comment: Да я вот для теста глубины и хочу) В libgdx я могу нарисовать через shaperenderer фигуры, а потом поверх них отриовать текстуру. Вот мне как бы надо получить их объединения, этих фигур. А можно с Вами связаться где-нибудь за пределами Stackoverflow? На прошлый мой вопрос по OpenGL и LibGDX вы тоже отвечали)